# Chat-room one-boxing for Etymonline and The Free Dictionary

Tags: feature-request, chat

The chat room can one-box lots of things, like wikipedia links and youtube videos and Google ngrams, making nice neat messages.

In ELU chat it would be very useful to be able to one-box Etymonline entries and The Free Dictionary entries using links.

I'd like to post a link like this:

> http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mitten

and get something like:

> mitten (n.) Look up mitten at Dictionary.com
>   late 14c., from Old French mitaine "mitten, half-glove" (12c.), from Old French mite "mitten," and from Medieval Latin mitta, which are perhaps from Middle High German mittemo, Old High German mittamo "middle, midmost" (reflecting notion of "half-glove"), or from Vulgar Latin *medietana "divided in the middle," from Latin medius (see medial (adj.)).

Comment: I'd like to think this would be possible, but the content on Etymonline is not under an open licence like Wikpedia or wiktionary, so it's not just a technology problem.

Comment: Do we have one-boxing for Wikitionary?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Oh. Wiktionary. _sigh_ I suppose that too. I hesitate to mention it but Urban Dictionary too?

Comment: @MattE.Эллен what does content have to do with it? It's just displaying a blurb at the top of the page which is fair game quoting not plagiarism fair use somethety something.

Comment: I think wictionary one boxes, I'm on my phone about to sleep, but that was how dictionary definition from the bots used to work. AFAIK Etymonline doesn't have a jsonp method for getting at its entries, which Wikipedia and wiktionary do, which is how they one-box. Screen scraping would be necessary to get entry data from Etymonline, and that is frowned upon, if not illegal.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I have the same concern regarding copyright, but it's worth mentioning that Stack Exchange also oneboxes Amazon and random images, so they're relying on Fair Use doctrine for the onebox feature rather than the creative commons license WIkipedia offers. I'm not even sure if our Wikipedia oneboxing complies with the terms of the CC-BY-SA license …